# Does the method argument in AJAX need to be upper case?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, get, case

Well basically what the title says, when making an AJAX request with JavaScript. Does the method, i.e. GET / POST, need to be upper case? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Even a yes or no will suffice.

Comment: Using what framework or method? Please show some code

Comment: Is that a problem if it does need to be uppercase? If so, why? I think if it does require uppercase then this is bad design. On the other hand, developers shouldn't have any difficulty following this convention (e.g. "post".toUpperCase() => "POST")

Comment: This is not using a framework, this is just a basic JavaScript AJAX call like so: xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);

Comment: @Samo No it is not a real problem, I can just conform, I am just wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about it at http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method

I quote

> *When the **open(method, url, async,
>    user, password)** method is invoked, the
>    user agent must run these steps
>    (unless otherwise indicated):*
>   ..
>   3. If method is a case-insensitive match for CONNECT, DELETE, GET, HEAD,
>   OPTIONS, POST, PUT, TRACE, or TRACK
>   subtract 0x20 from each byte in the
>   range 0x61 (ASCII a) to 0x7A (ASCII
>   z).
>   ..

which means it will automatically convert it to upper case on its own ..

So it seems to have some significance (*preferring uppercase*), and i would suggest you use uppercase just to avoid implementation flaws (*improbable*).

Comment: Okay thanks, I will convert to upper case no matter what. Nice to know. Thanks for the link.